# Data normalisation for a newbie

Tags: dataset, normalization, excel

I am new to data analysis and I have been given a task to compare safety of trams compared to buses. Since there are far more buses than trams, I was introduced to the concept of normalisation by passenger km, which can allow the comparison to happen in an accurate way.
Personally, I tried googling this but could not find anything useful to go forward with the project.
Does anyone know where to go for explanations like these? I am keen to learn more about data normalisation, but not understanding the concept puts me in an awkward spot.
How does passenger km help in this case? Someone I know said that by dividing, for example, the number of incidents related to trams/buses and diving them by the passenger kms, I would get accurate data that would reflect on the graphs I would need to make for demonstrations.

If anyone can help and explain this to me in a basic way, I would be extremely grateful.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

I would not call this "normalization".  If you want a statistical term, maybe "scaling" but I would prefer simply saying "transformation" or "change of variables".

Generally, this sort of thing involves thinking and experience. I don't know of a general guide, as each situation is different. (This is common in statistics and data analysis; the pervasive idea that you can just follow a set of rules and that's it is false).

For this particular case, think about how you think about "safety". There are different possible answers, but certainly one is "for each km I travel on this mode of transport, how likely am I to get hurt?" (or "be in an accident" or "be killed" etc.)  That is provided by looking at passenger km. But you might want a different measure!

One thing is to look at who is giving you this task and what they might want. An insurance company might be looking for different things than a consumer advocate.

Comment: This is not the usual understanding of "transformation" in the statistical literature, because it is not purely a function of the variable of interest.  It might be better and more perspicuous to characterize it as choosing a mode of data *expression.*